# Android Game - Screen Flickers When an Entity Removed From The List

Tags: java, 2d, android, rendering, kotlin

I am using Canvas in my android game. When I remove a no longer displayed entity in my entity list, all other entities are flickering for a brief time. When it's not removed, there is no such problem. But since I am not a big fan of memory leaks, that's not an option.

The canvas rendering system is already double-buffered by design and I have utterly no idea how to fix such a problem.
I have thought maybe it is because the list is sorting itself after the item removal and tried changing it to a Set, but that didn't work either.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Structure of the code:

```
private val gameObjects: List<GameObject> = mutableListOf()
    
    fun update(deltaTime: Long)
    {
        gameObjects.forEach {
            it.update(deltaTime)
    }

 fun render(canvas: Canvas)
    {
      gameObjects.forEach {
         when (getVisibilityStatus(it.virtualY))
         {
            VisibilityStatus.VISIBLE -> it.render(canvas, virtualToPhysicalY(it.virtualY))

            VisibilityStatus.BELOW_SCREEN ->
            {
              if (virtualToPhysicalY(it.virtualY) > screenSizePairXY.second)
                gameObjects.remove(it)
            
            }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently removing an item from a list that you are iterating isn't such a good idea. Separating the cleanup/removal process from the render for each loop fixed the issue.

```
      private val gameObjects: List<GameObject> = mutableListOf()
      private val gameObjectsToRemove: List<GameObject> = mutableListOf()

    
   /**
    * Removes the invisible objects (if any) to save memory
    */
      private fun cleanUp()
        {
            gameObjectsToRemove.forEach {
                gameObjects.remove(it)
            }
            gameObjectsToRemove.clear()
        }
        
        fun update(deltaTime: Long)
        {
            cleanUp()
            gameObjects.forEach {
                it.update(deltaTime)
        }
    
     fun render(canvas: Canvas)
        {
          gameObjects.forEach {
             when (getVisibilityStatus(it.virtualY))
             {
                VisibilityStatus.VISIBLE -> it.render(canvas, virtualToPhysicalY(it.virtualY))
    
                VisibilityStatus.BELOW_SCREEN ->
                {
                  if (virtualToPhysicalY(it.virtualY) > screenSizePairXY.second)
                    gameObjectsToRemove.add(it)
                
                }
             }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to use `removeAll` instead of calling `remove` in a loop.

Comment: Yeah sure why not, thanks